# Inequality of intervals lengths.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(I_j)_{j = 1}^n$ be a finite collection of intervals that covers the rationals in $[0, 1]$. Prove that $\sum_{j = 1}^n \ell (I_j) \geq 1$. (Here, $\ell (I)$ denotes the length of the interval $I$.)

I thought the following: consider $\mathfrak{m}^\ast$ the exterior Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. We have that $\Bbb Q \cap [0, 1] \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n I_j$. Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, we have $[0, 1] \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n I_j$, hence: $$\mathfrak{m}^\ast [0, 1] \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathfrak{m}^\ast I_j = \sum_{j = 1}^n \ell (I_j) \implies 1 \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n \ell (I_j)$$

as we wanted.

However, I'm not sure that $\Bbb Q$ being dense really implies that $[0, 1] \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n I_j$. Also, I would rather not use that $\Bbb Q$ is dense. Can someone give me some light here, please? Alternative solutions are welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: You can show that $[0,1]$ is contained in that union, but you did not give a valid reason.  (Note that if there were infinitely many intervals allowed, it would no longer be true.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose (without loss of generality; why?) that the intervals $\{I_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are closed. If $\sum_{i=1}^n \ell(I_i) = 1-\epsilon < 1$, then $[0,1]\setminus \left(\cup_{i=1}^n I_i\right)$ is an open set of measure $\epsilon$, so it contains an open ball.

Edit: To be more precise, $A := [0,1]\setminus \left(\cup_{i=1}^n I_i\right)$ is an open set of measure *at least* $\epsilon$:
$$m(A) = m([0,1]) - m\left([0,1]\cap \cup_{i=1}^n I_i\right) \geq 1-\sum_{i=1}^n \ell(I_i)$$ by finite subadditivity.

Alternatively, it is no loss of generality to assume the $I_i$ are disjoint and contained in $[0,1]$. We may simply take $\{\tilde{I}_j\}_{j=1}^{\tilde{n}}$ in $[0,1]$ by chopping off anything else, and disjoint by redistributing overlap whenever $I_i \cap I_j \neq \emptyset$ to new sets $\tilde{I}_k$, $k > n$. Then the contradiction will still follow because we prove $\sum_{i=1}^{\tilde{n}} \ell(\tilde{I}_j)$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n \ell(I_i) \geq \sum_{j=1}^{\tilde{n}} \ell(\tilde{I}_j).$$

Comment: You're using that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable, with $B \subset A$, and finite measures, then $\mathfrak{m}(A \setminus B) = \mathfrak{m}A - \mathfrak{m}B$, right? Just to see if I'm thinking right.

Comment: Correct: $m(A\setminus B) := m(A\cap B^c) = m(A) - m(A \cap B) = m(A) - m(B)$, where $B \subset A$ can be taken as (again, w.l.o.g.) $B := \cup_{i=1}^n I_i \subset [0,1] =: A$. However, an additional assumption or a slight modification of the argument is needed to treat the (non-)disjointness of the $I_i$ -- see edit.